# Particle system not emitting particles in game mode? (+extra information)

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system, particles

Situation: 3D Game - I want a lava pool with bubbles, so the particle system got a parent. (the pool)

My problem is that my particle system isn't emitting particles automatically, if I instantiate them. A few information:

1. The bubbles are blocked by the pool, so they are only visible at the edge of the pool. (I tried moving my system upwards, but that didn't solve the problem.
2. If I place the prefab in the editor, only problem #1 happens.
3. If I pause the game then continue, the particle emitter (spawned via script) starts working, and only problem #1 happens. (parent blocks particles)
4. If I prewarm the particle system, it emits particles after start (so pause is not needed), but I don't know why, because I've got another prefab which is working perfectly, and its options are the same, the only difference is that prewarm is turned off. (so why is prewarm required the lava pool?)

Sorry for my English, I hope you can understand me. :)

Comment: It sounds like a 2-D game- please correct me if I'm wrong.
Have you tried spawning the particle system slightly closer to the camera than the pool?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post :) It's 3D

Comment: It sounds like a shader issue to me. I suggest experimenting with different shader types on your particle system.

Comment: That was fast :D I changed it from Particles/Alpha Blended to Particles/Additive. But without prewarm, it doesn't emits via script, but with prewarm, I can't delay the emitting.

Comment: ...But it fixes the issue of visibility?

Comment: Only Problem #2. But I have to prewarm it if I wan't the instantiated ones to work, but if I prewarm it, I can't set a starting delay.

Comment: Have you tried setting the 'Start Delay' field on the prefab?

Comment: If I prewarm I can't set Starting Delay (it's grey), and if I don't enable prewarm, I can set starting delay, and it works correctly, but the instantiated ones won't work, because they are not prewarmed.

Comment: Why does your particle system not work if it is not prewarmed? I think that's the problem to solve now that everything else works.

Comment: There is Empty GameObject which contains my lava pool (because there is an animation for my lava pool, which scales the pool to 0 then to 1, so I can't scale the pool itself), The Lava pool is a sphere with 1,0,1 scale, an animator, a script, and a material with standard shader. The lava pool contains my particle system, which is this: https://i.gyazo.com/879c4c62ec372d306496ce1970e43987.png
https://i.gyazo.com/9983b4990c8537d91811302b32f35e5a.png
If I put the prefab to the scene, it works correctly without prewarm. But if I instantiate it, it only works if it's prewarmed.

Comment: I suggest debugging to see why it's not working when it's not prewarmed. If you can solve that, it sounds like you'll have everything you need :)

Comment: Yes, but I've been debugging and trying every combination of settings for maybe 8 hours, that's why I asked it here, because I am stuck :D Now I'm gonna get some sleep because it's 2 am here. Tomorrow I will try running it via scripts. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I tried this:

Debug.Log(transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().isPlaying);

And it says true but I can't see anything. (Prewarm is turned off right now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Unity Bug. I updated to 5.3.2 and it's fixed now. Thanks for you help btw :)